# .NET Core DateTime doesn't correctly insert/update DateTime column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, vue.js

I'm trying to insert some `DATETIME` into my SQL Server database from .NET Core & Entity Framework, but I'm having a weird behaviour happening.

First of all, the data inserted is taken from a VueJS API call and the data I'm sending is something like this:

```
...
lastModified: "2019-10-28T10:54:07.556Z"
...
```

Then, what I receive on my C# backend seems correct, I'm receiving it as an object from my model, and the `lastModified` property seems ok:

[image]

I then insert my data into my database with the following code:

```
using (var context = new TestContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
    var originalSave = context.SauvegardeIntervention.FirstOrDefault(s => s.IdIntervention == id);
    context.Entry(originalSave).CurrentValues.SetValues(save);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return true;
}
```

And the insert is done correctly, but, the time part of the datetime is like erased when looking at what is inserted in my database:

[image]

But when I'm retrieving the `DateTime` property, I get the same exact object that I sent before...

My question is why my `datetime` property doesn't have a time part in my database?

My EF model for this object is :

```
public partial class SauvegardeIntervention
{
    public int IdIntervention { get; set; }
    public string SauvegardeContent { get; set; }
    public bool? CurrentlyInUse { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }

    public virtual Intervention IdInterventionNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

The SQL Server table corresponding to that is like that :

[image]

Comment: Please show your EF model, or ideally a [mcve].

Comment: What's the column type? Do you have have a custom logic in the `get` property?

Comment: When using entity framework, what column type does the builder have e.g modelBuilder.Properties<SauvegardeIntervention>()
.Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));

Comment: I added the structure of the SauvegardeIntervention object, the model is kinda long so I can't really copy it here

Answer (score 1):

Well eVolve was on the rigt track I guess, I just checked the model back and I had

```
entity.Property(e => e.LastModified)
                .HasColumnName("lastModified")
                .HasColumnType("date");
```

Instead of

```
entity.Property(e => e.LastModified)
                .HasColumnName("lastModified")
                .HasColumnType("datetime2");
```